JSONDecodeError LanguageToolError:
I am using language_tool_python to perform spelling correction on my dataset which has a text column.
tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US') 

def text_preprocessing_pipeline(df=attack_data,spelling_check=True):
    if spelling_check:
        print('Text Preprocessing: Spelling Check')
        df['text_check'] = df['text_check'].progress_apply(lambda x: tool.correct(x))
        tool.close()
   return df

However, I get this error. I would appreciate any advice.

JSONDecodeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\language_tool_python\server.py in _query_server(self, url, params, num_tries)
247                     try:
--> 248                         return response.json()
249                     except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
899
~\anaconda3\lib\json_init_.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
358     if cls is None:
~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
338         end = _w(s, end).end()
~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
356         return obj, end
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LanguageToolError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 attack_data_clean_with_stopword = text_preprocessing_pipeline(
2                                     df=attack_data,
3                                     textual_statistics=True,
4                                     remove_url=True,
5                                     remove_email=True,
 in text_preprocessing_pipeline(df, textual_statistics, remove_url, remove_email, remove_user_mention, remove_html, remove_space_single_char, normalize_elongated_char, normalize_emoji, normalize_emoticon, normalize_accented, lower_case, normalize_slang, normalize_badterm, spelling_check, normalize_contraction, term_list, remove_numeric, remove_stopword, keep_pronoun, remove_punctuation, pos, ner, lemmatise)
164     if spelling_check:
165         print('Text Preprocessing: Spelling Check')
--> 166         df['text_check'] = df['text_check'].progress_apply(lambda x: tool.correct(x))
167         tool.close()
168
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py in inner(df, func, *args, **kwargs)
765                 # on the df using our wrapper (which provides bar updating)
766                 try:
--> 767                     return getattr(df, df_function)(wrapper, **kwargs)
768                 finally:
769                     t.close()
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
3846             else:
3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
3849
3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
760                     # take a fast or slow code path; so stop when t.total==t.n
761                     t.update(n=1 if not t.total or t.n < t.total else 0)
--> 762                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
763
764                 # Apply the provided function (in **kwargs)
 in (x)
164     if spelling_check:
165         print('Text Preprocessing: Spelling Check')
--> 166         df['text_check'] = df['text_check'].progress_apply(lambda x: tool.correct(x))
167         tool.close()
168
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\language_tool_python\server.py in correct(self, text)
163     def correct(self, text: str) -> str:
164         """Automatically apply suggestions to the text."""
--> 165         return correct(text, self.check(text))
166
167     def enable_spellchecking(self):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\language_tool_python\server.py in check(self, text)
139         """Match text against enabled rules."""
140         url = urllib.parse.urljoin(self._url, 'check')
--> 141         response = self._query_server(url, self._create_params(text))
142         matches = response['matches']
143         return [Match(match) for match in matches]
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\language_tool_python\server.py in _query_server(self, url, params, num_tries)
256                             print(response)
257                             print(response.content)
--> 258                         raise  LanguageToolError(response.content.decode())
259             except (IOError, http.client.HTTPException) as e:
260                 if self._remote is False:
LanguageToolError: 












The problem does not seem to arise from the installed packages.
